# Are there any performace gains to using Varnish along php-fpm and nginx?

Tags: centos, nginx, performance, php-fpm, varnish

PHP-FPM 5.6 and Nginx 1.6.2 would no doubt give maximum performance, at-least speed wise. So, I would like to know if there are any pros/cons to adding varnish cache to gain probably few more speed. I have read many blogs that state nginx + varnish alone is a bit overkill, but I still haven't gotten a feedback that can justify this.

Comment: This is depends too much on the workload itself. I think nginx does a pretty good job at caching itself and Varnish will not really help that much but that is more of an opinion. The only way for you to find out is to test the setup.

Comment: I don't see the point to add varnish when nginx can do the whole job. You won't get better result with this. Nginx is super fast and rock solid at pretty much everything. You probably will even have worse results if you have them on the same rig.

Comment: I found nginx's caching to be perfectly serviceable, making Varnish redundant.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have been searching for a while, to come to the same conclusion myself. But, it seems afterall varnish does add ~%5 performance on top of Php-fpm, and Nginx. I guess this boils down to, if having "yet another" software running to gain +5% is redundant or not. I have to go with no :)

Comment: Yes, but are you actually using nginx's caching?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes. Nothing fancy [according to this at-least](http://aspyct.org/blog/2012/08/20/setting-up-http-cache-and-gzip-with-nginx/)

Comment: @Bimlik1 So you are not. You are just sending headers for client-side (browser & proxies) caching. You are not caching anything on the server-side. Take a look at [fastcgi_cache](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_cache) to cache php-fpm responses. There is also much to tune in nginx before going further (like open file cache, event polling, buffering etc).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you use nginx. If you are not using any of the caching features of nginx, then you will definitely gain from Varnish.
You have to decide what function each will have. 
This said, if you are looking to do "double-caching", I doubt this is a good idea.

Perhaps you could tell us about how your stack is set up...

Comment: I just have a couple of PHP based sites. I am just trying to gain more speed, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Actually **it depends on your application**.

It doesn't make sense to put a Varnish proxy in front of a Nginx web-server if you serve only static files.

Regarding the acceleration of your PHP applications you can already use Nginx (see [fastcgi_cache](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_cache)) to apply a caching layer. This could be already a simple solution to gain additional speed.

However there are cases where using Varnish could be helpful:

- ability to purge cached content
- complex caching rules
- use of ESI (edge side includes)

**Example**

The PHP application has to send proper caching headers.

```
server {
    listen          80;
    listen          [::]:80;
    server_name     www.example.com;

    root    /var/www/www.example.com/htdocs;

    # CVE 2013-4547
    if ($request_uri ~ " ") {
            return 444;
    }

    location / {
            try_files $uri index.php?url=$uri&$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            # global access log is off but for PHP we'd like to log
            access_log                      /var/log/nginx/access.log vhosts;

            # use fastCGI
            fastcgi_keep_conn               on;
            fastcgi_pass                    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index                   index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME      $fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_buffer_size             128k;
            fastcgi_buffers                 256 16k;
            fastcgi_busy_buffers_size       256k;
            fastcgi_temp_file_write_size    256k;

            # activate caching for fastCGI
            fastcgi_cache                   php;
            fastcgi_cache_bypass            $cookie_PHPSESSID; # do not cache if session is active
            fastcgi_cache_key               "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri"; # cache key
            fastcgi_cache_use_stale         error timeout invalid_header http_500; # stale on error
            fastcgi_cache_valid             200 301 720s; # cache only HTTP-200 and HTTP-301 responses and define a TTL
            fastcgi_pass_header             Set-Cookie; # allow Set-Cookie header
            fastcgi_no_cache                $cookie_PHPSESSID; # do not cache if session is active

            # include system wide fastCGI settings (Ubuntu/Debian style)
            include                         fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: I still can't make nginx to cache file. Is there is guide somewhere on how to do this?

Comment: Actually, varnish would be faster if a high proportion of content can be served from cache, and particularly if it's lots of small requests. *Very* few people serve enough static content for this to matter though.

Comment: I have added an example of fastCGI cache configuration